# Storing, reading, and writing linked data

Tags: python

I have a Python script which takes IDs, a randomly generated hexidecimal string, and stores the two in a text file seperated by ¦ in this fashion:

```
hexidecimal = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(15))
f.write(id + "¦" + hexidecimal + "\n")

1¦b8185c6843197fdf03cdaed57b69095
2¦b8185c6843197fdf03cdaed57b69096
3¦b8185c6843197fdf03cdaed57b69097
4¦b8185c6843197fdf03cdaed57b69098
5¦b8185c6843197fdf03cdaed57b69099
```

What I want to do is read this file with a separate script and do a search for the hex and get out the associated ID, which I can then do things with.

How would I go about doing that?

As a side note, my random hexidecimal string could technically contain the ¦ character which would mess things up. It's unlikely but I'd like to account for it. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: what have you tried? Also, how can a hexadecimal string contain `|`??

Comment: I managed to work it out using a dictionary and assigning key/value from reading the text file.